# Joomla 2.5 - How to fix 404 Not Found error after restoration using akeeba kickstart

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

After kickstarting a Joomla 2.5.22 on a new server in a sub-folder, the only page that works well is the home page, the rest give me (404 Not Found).

Tried many solutions found on the web even on Akeeba website [here](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/troubleshooter/prbasicts.html) but still can't solve this issue.

I know that it's a path issue as if I add the sub-folder name in the address of the page that gives 404 error, the page displays properly.

Eg : www.testing.ca/**mysub-folder**/contact.html  = Works well !!!

How do I dynamically add the sub-folder name for the entire site? or a best solution to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess` file, replace the following:

```
# RewriteBase
```

With:

```
RewriteBase /mysub-folder/
```

Open your `configuration.php` file, and change:

```
$live_site = ''
```

to:

```
$live_site = 'http://www.[yourdomain].com';
```

Also in the configuration.php file, change the `tmp` and the `log` paths to the correct physical location.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did it but still not working. I noticed that the paths for **tmp** and **log** did replace themselves automatically as it's seems in order.  The domain is "http://dev.tasch.co.za/airportshuttle/", there are links at the buttom, if you click on one of these link, you'll get 404 error. Add the subfolder **airportshuttle** it'll work fine. So basically on these links, inside Joomla, everything must start from **http://dev.tasch.co.za/airportshuttle/**  but it is NOT starting from that !!!

Comment: I know I can change all these links manually but I don't want to do that, I need a dynamic solution.

Comment: I also just ran repair and optimize of the database via phpmyadmin but still not working.